# How to know which graphic card is compatible with my motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I have an Asus N55SF, I had problems with the with motherboard and the graphic card itself (Nvidia GT555M). So i bought a new motherboard, and i thought i could use the laptop without the graphic card, because my processor have a built in intel HD 3000 graphic card, but the repair shop told me that I need an external graphic cards (is that even true?).
He also said that laptop graphic cards are hard to find and mostly i wont find a compatible one.
So is it true that i need an external card, and how do i check if it is compatible or not?

Chipset: is an Intel® HM65 
Processor: i7 2670QM

Comment: The `Nvidia GT555M` is soldered onto your motherboard, so the only way to replace it, would be to remove it.  The process of removing it is not something you can do as an end user, and the equipment to remove it the correct way is 6-7 thousand american dollars.

Comment: no is not soldered, it can be easily removed, by 2 screws, i already removed it, its has a pci like port

Comment: So MXM  2.0 or MXM 3.0?

Comment: I have no idea, in the asus specification, it just say Gt555m

Comment: how do i check if it is 3 or 2? and does this mean i can use anything mxm card?

Comment: ok so i checked, its a MXM 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Its a laptop. Your options for a video card upgrade are fairly limited.

There's a laptop specific series of 'removable' video cards called MXM. Sadly they're only remotely standardised, and you can't put an arbitrary MXM card into an arbitrary system. I didn't have much luck working out if this is an MXM card.

However, if the motherboards are the same, in theory, you could put a MXM card from the old motherboard into the new one.

"but the repair shop told me that I need an external graphic cards (is that even true?)." - More likely than not it should be a soldered on part if its needed. Else, you need to get a MXM card from the very same model of laptop, ideally.

"He also said that laptop graphic cards are hard to find and mostly i wont find a compatible one."

Kind of true.

That said, for a *definitive* answer, you need a service manual. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader, cause I do sympathise since that is often an exercise in frustration, to the point where I google for this *before* I buy a laptop,  'in case' I need to do some off warranty work on it.

That said, I'd ask them if they could then remove the GPU from the old system and install it in the new one.

Comment: the GT555m is removable ..